# Como verificar se o input está vazio com Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de que meu form desabilitasse os 'input radio' quando o 'input name' estivesse vazio,
tentei o seguinte: toda vez que o valor do input text mudar, verifica se esta vazio, se estiver desabilita o input radio

```js
  $("input[name='new-sale-cli']").on('change', function() { 

    if($.trim($("input[name='new-sale-cli']").val() == '')) {
          $("input[name='payment-option']").prop('disabled',true);
            console.log($("input[name='new-sale-cli']").val());
        } 
        
    else {
          $("input[name='payment-option']").prop('disabled', false);
        }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" name="new-sale-cli">
```

O problema é que esta entrando no if sempre, ate quando o input text NAO esta vazio, ou seja, sempre vai estar desabilitado.
Ja tentei usar o 'change', 'on change' na função,
ja tentei usar o 'is(:empty'), ' =="" ' e o resultado e sempre o mesmo,

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: `$("input[name='new-sale-cli']").val() == ''` é uma expressão que retorna `true` ou `false` (se o valor é igual à string vazia ou não). Ao passar tudo isso para `trim`, ele acaba convertendo o booleano para string, resultando em "true" ou "false", e em JavaScript strings não-vazias sempre são verdadeiras, portanto sempre entrará no `if`. Basta fazer `if($.trim($("input[name='new-sale-cli']").val()))`

Comment: Ola  hkotsubo! Eu fiz dessa maneira e agora esta funcionando ao contrario kkk
O objetivo é: se o campo estiver vazio, desabilite os input radio.
No caso, ele esta habilitando os input radio quando o campo esta vazio, e desabilitando quando ha algo escrito. Eu poderia simplesmente inverter, mas nao estaria certo, ja presenciou esse tipo de caso?

Comment: Coloque assim: `if(!$.trim($("input[name='new-sale-cli']").val()))`

Comment: O sinal `!` antes da expressão indica se ela é `false`.

Comment: Esta funcionando agora, mas a logica nao esta errada? "se for false, desabilita" quando era pra ser "se for true desabilita", futuramente numa manutenção pode causar confusao, estou certo?

Comment: Se for vazio (`false`), desabilita. O `if` sempre verifica se a condição é verdadeira, não se a expressão é verdadeira.

Comment: Acho que entendi. Se o campo estiver vazio, o javascript entende como 'false', e se tiver preenchido, entende como true, nesse caso é uma questao de sintaxe,

Answer (score 0):

SOLUÇÃO FINAL:

Graças a ajuda do hkotsubo e do Sam, a resolução final ficou assim:

```js
  $("input[name='new-sale-cli']").on('change', function() { 

     if(!$.trim($("input[name='new-sale-cli']").val())) {
        $("input[name='payment-option']").prop('disabled', true);
        console.log('vazio');
      } else {
            $("input[name='payment-option']").prop('disabled', false);
        }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" name="new-sale-cli">
```

O JS entende que campo vazio: false e campo preenchido: true.
O codigo diz: "se for false, desabilita os campos"